# Read two input from nodered

Tags: javascript, firebase, node-red

My current project using `node-red` and `firebase` db. I created a path and child (target & output) in the firebase and the target is key in manually as fix number while the output is the sensor output with the counter.
Im trying to compare the values using function node (if `output > target`) payload should be **target value** and (if `output < target`) payload should be **output value**.

How to read both input from firebase child as the nodes and compare for the value?

Attached nodes picture that may help.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `join` node from the default set of nodes.

It can be configured in a number of ways, but one is to wait for 2 inputs and then send a message containing the `msg.payload` from both those messages in a single message.

You can then compare those 2 parts in a `switch` or `function` node.

The simplest way will be to set different topic values for the 2 firebase nodes and then use these as keys in the output `msg.payload` object.